# How to make links visible with "inset-0" gradient div?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I have the following nextjs component "Navbar.jsx":

```
'use client';

import { motion } from 'framer-motion';

import styles from '../styles';
import { navVariants } from '../utils/motion';
import Link from 'next/link';

const Navbar = () => (
  <motion.nav
    variants={navVariants}
    initial="hidden"
    whileInView="show"
    className={`${styles.xPaddings} py-8 relative`}
  >

    <div className="absolute w-[50%] inset-0 gradient-01" />
    <div
      className={`${styles.innerWidth} mx-auto flex justify-between gap-8`}
    >
      <Link href='/'>NAV TEST LINK</Link>
      <Link href='/'>
      <img
        src="/search.svg"
        alt="search"
        className="w-[24px] h-[24px] object-contain"
      />
      </Link>
      <Link href='/'>NAV TEST LINK 2</Link>
      <h2 className="font-extrabold text-[24px] leading-[30.24px] text-white">
        METAVERSUS
      </h2>
      <Link href='/'>NAV TEST LINK 3</Link>
      <Link href='/'>
      <img
        src="/menu.svg"
        alt="menu"
        className="w-[24px] h-[24px] object-contain"
      />
      </Link>

    </div>
  </motion.nav>
);

export default Navbar;
```

I realized that the first div `<div className="absolute w-[50%] inset-0 gradient-01" />` is blocking some of the Link elements and makign the hyperlink not visible. Is there a way, besides adding "z-10" to all the Link elements, to make them all visible while keeping the "inset-0" div as is?

Comment: “The first div…” this div appears to be unclosed. Could you check your structure? Is it a parent of the next div or not?

Comment: It's "self closed" as <div.../>